# Geometry transformation in function translation

Tags: functions, analytic-geometry, transformation, geometric-transformation

Let $f(x)=x+3$. let's say we want a new function that is a translation of $f(x)$ by $5$ units to the right. If we will denote by $x'$  the new coordinate, Then For all $x$ , $x'=x+5\,\Rightarrow\, x=x'-5$.
After substituting $x=x'-5$ in f(x) we Will obtain a new function, $f(x'-5)=x'-2$.

Then the new function is $g(x)=f(x-5)=x-2$

My question is why do we need to substitute $x=x'-5$ in $f(x)$? ( what is the logic behind it?). Does it mean we just ends up with the same function? and why once we find the new function , We change $x'$ to $x$ (is there any meaning?) i don't get it

Answer (score 1):

Similar questions have been answered over the years, but since I didn't find a simple picture that explains this question geometrically:

[image: Translation of Cartesian coordinates]

In the Cartesian plane, we've introduced a new Cartesian coordinate system with its origin at location $(x_{0}, y_{0})$. If we denote the new coordinates $(x', y')$, then the formula $(x', y') = (x - x_{0}, y - y_{0})$ *transforms* the location of each point $(x, y)$ in the original system to the coordinates $(x', y')$ in the new system. Particularly, $(x, y) = (x_{0}, y_{0})$ corresponds to $(x', y') = (0, 0)$.

The graph of a function is a set of points independent of a coordinate system. When we write $y = f(x)$, this equation serves as a *condition* that a point $(x, y)$ may or may not satisfy. Points that satisfy the equation *lie on the graph*.

Suppose we ask, "What equation in $(x', y')$ describes the same set of points?" Since $x = x' + x_{0}$ and $y = y' + y_{0}$, we have
$$
y = f(x)\quad\text{if and only if}\quad
y' + y_{0} = f(x' + x_{0})
$$
as conditions on the plane. Here we had to express the old coordinates in terms of the new coordinates. In fancy terms, we needed to *invert* our translational change of coordinates.

Moving the new origin to the *left* moves the graph *right* in the new coordinates, and moving the origin *up* moves the graph *down* in the new coordinates. That's a fundamental property of reality and how we measure it.